# How to find props of nested objects in array JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested

I have an array of objects that looks something like this:

```js
const roles = [
  {
    "id": "833ffe3d-cc24-4157-966c-5f8ceb856f4e",
    "hidden": false,
    "modified": "2020-03-20T15:14:12.689Z",
    "label": "Solution 2",
    "shortname": "Solution 2",
    "description": "Solution 2 description",
    "className": "Solution",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "f1708329-eb9f-4042-bbe7-cdd1ff41b1b7",
        "hidden": false,
        "modified": "2020-03-20T15:14:12.293Z",
        "label": "USER CUSTOM ROLE",
        "displayName": "USER CUSTOM ROLE DISPLAY NAME",
        "className": "Role"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "1a36709f-4de2-4f93-bf8e-57811d36e9f3",
    "hidden": false,
    "modified": "2020-03-20T15:14:12.668Z",
    "label": "Solution 1",
    "shortname": "Solution 1",
    "description": "Solution 1 description",
    "className": "Solution",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "e824afbd-8b19-4363-b6fa-dd604f445cef",
        "hidden": false,
        "modified": "2020-03-20T15:14:12.271Z",
        "label": "USER ROLE",
        "displayName": "USER ROLE DISPLAY NAME",
        "className": "Role"
      },
      {
        "id": "8f2600d0-5328-4d41-8270-2eb10541860f",
        "hidden": false,
        "modified": "2020-03-20T15:14:12.095Z",
        "label": "BASE LOGIN ROLE",
        "displayName": "DISPLAY NAME - BASE LOGIN ROLE",
        "className": "Role"
      },
      {
        "id": "a14ce471-b792-4a5d-95ad-b9abb5dbe45c",
        "hidden": false,
        "modified": "2020-03-20T15:14:12.102Z",
        "label": "ORGANIZATION GLOBAL ROLE",
        "displayName": "DISPLAY NAME - GLOBAL ROLE",
        "className": "Role"
      },
      {
        "id": "d4a7d6ac-1663-48be-9fed-ce2a908f28f1",
        "hidden": false,
        "modified": "2020-03-20T15:14:12.130Z",
        "label": "DEPARTMENT 1 ROLE",
        "className": "Role"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Point of my concern is **id**, **label** and **children** of these objects. As you can see, some of the roles objects contain their own roles array. And I have another array of selected roles, which looks like this:

```js
const selected = ["Solution 1", "USER ROLE", "DEPARTMENT 1 ROLE"];
```

What I want is to create flat array of IDs corresponding to the selected roles, e.g. for this 
selected array it will be (order is not important):

```js
const result = ["d4a7d6ac-1663-48be-9fed-ce2a908f28f1", "e824afbd-8b19-4363-b6fa-dd604f445cef", "1a36709f-4de2-4f93-bf8e-57811d36e9f3"];
```

So my algorithm in pseudocode is:
1. Check root level object.
2. If it's label is in selected array, push it's id to the result array.
3. If it has children prop, check all it's children for the same condition.
4. Repeat for all other objects.

I've been only able to come up with very smelly function on this own and it still doesn't solve problem of the nested roles. My function is:

```js
function getIds(arr, names) {
  let result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
      if (arr[i].label == names[j]) {
        result.push(arr[i].id);
      }
      if (arr[i].children) {
        for (let k = 0; k < arr[i].children.length; k++) {
          if (arr[i].children[k].label == names[j]) {
            result.push(arr[i].children[k].id);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

I know, there are much more cleaner and prettier solutions, I just can't come up with one. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would flatten the array what you have with roles using [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). Then simply with [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) matching the labels with the array elements and returning the ids.

Try the following:

```js
const selected = ["Solution 1", "USER ROLE", "DEPARTMENT 1 ROLE"];
const roles = [{ "id": "833ffe3d-cc24-4157-966c-5f8ceb856f4e", "hidden": false, "modified": "2020-03-20T15:14:12.689Z",        "label": "Solution 2",        "shortname": "Solution 2",        "description": "Solution 2 description",        "className": "Solution",        "children": [{            "id": "f1708329-eb9f-4042-bbe7-cdd1ff41b1b7",            "hidden": false,            "modified": "2020-03-20T15:14:12.293Z",            "label": "USER CUSTOM ROLE",            "displayName": "USER CUSTOM ROLE DISPLAY NAME",            "className": "Role"          }        ]      },      {        "id": "1a36709f-4de2-4f93-bf8e-57811d36e9f3",        "hidden": false,        "modified": "2020-03-20T15:14:12.668Z",        "label": "Solution 1",        "shortname": "Solution 1",        "description": "Solution 1 description",        "className": "Solution",        "children": [{            "id": "e824afbd-8b19-4363-b6fa-dd604f445cef",            "hidden": false,            "modified": "2020-03-20T15:14:12.271Z",            "label": "USER ROLE",            "displayName": "USER ROLE DISPLAY NAME",            "className": "Role"          },          {            "id": "8f2600d0-5328-4d41-8270-2eb10541860f",            "hidden": false,            "modified": "2020-03-20T15:14:12.095Z",            "label": "BASE LOGIN ROLE",            "displayName": "DISPLAY NAME - BASE LOGIN ROLE",            "className": "Role"          },          {            "id": "a14ce471-b792-4a5d-95ad-b9abb5dbe45c",            "hidden": false,            "modified": "2020-03-20T15:14:12.102Z",            "label": "ORGANIZATION GLOBAL ROLE",            "displayName": "DISPLAY NAME - GLOBAL ROLE",            "className": "Role"          },          {            "id": "d4a7d6ac-1663-48be-9fed-ce2a908f28f1",            "hidden": false,            "modified": "2020-03-20T15:14:12.130Z",            "label": "DEPARTMENT 1 ROLE",            "className": "Role"          }        ]      }    ];

const flat = roles.flatMap(e => e.children.concat(e));
const result = selected.map(e => flat.find(f => f.label === e).id);

console.log(selected);
console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps!